# Start JBoss EAP 7.2 in background

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am new to JBoss EAP administration. I know how to start JBoss EAP. In linux environment I run

```
sh standalone.sh
```

and the JBoss server starts. The problem is when I disconnect the session i.e. close the putty window from which sh command has been run, the server also stops. So how will I be able to start and stop JBoss EAP in background so that it won't stop when the putty window is closed, but rather I can start or stop it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a `&` at the end of the command. Something like `sh standalone.sh &`.

For a better approach have a look at the [EAP documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/installation_guide/configuring_jboss_eap_to_run_as_a_service) for running EAP as a service.